# In python How to ensure that seed in using randint keeps changing when i am trying to pick a random number?

Tags: python, dataframe, random

```
def claims(dataframe):
    dataframe.loc[(dataframe.severity ==1),'claims_made']= randint(200, 20000)
    return dataframe
```

here 'severity' is an existing column and 'claims_made' is a new column, I want to have the randint keep picking different values that are being assigned to the 'claims_made' column. because for now it's just  picking one random value out of the bucket specified and is assigning the same value to all the rows that satisfy the condition

Comment: Only seed the random generator *once*.

Comment: I have close to 130,000 rows in the data frame, and I need different values to be picked up every time the condition is true, i know how to do it using for loop, but not sure if I can do it inside a function by somehow specifying the random seed to keep changing

Comment: @Mark Ransom how to seed the random gen once?

Comment: Do it once at the start of your program.  Since the code you posted doesn't show any seeding at all, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect.  You have, indeed, seeded the RNG only once.  The RNG returns a random number and updates the seed.  The problem is that you *called* `random` only once, rather than once for each row.  You explicitly use that one return value for your entire data frame.

Comment: Random values do not guarantee not to reuse the same value, by definition of randomness. If you want to make sure it is not reused, check yourself.

Comment: @Prune what you say make sense, but how do i get a random number for each row, also  i do not have any seed specified in the code , so probably it is picking one at random, i want that seed which is being picked up to change for each row the condition holds true and that is my query

Comment: Please add a sample dataframe to your question so that we can write complete responses.

Comment: @zvone if the random number being picked up gets repeated even for 100 or 300 times out of 130,000 rows i don't mind as long as there is a good distribution in the selection of random numbers between (200, 20000) and not just one random number for all the rows which satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets a single `randint` and applies that one value to the column you create. Its the same as if you had done

```
val = randint(20, 20000)
dataframe.loc[(dataframe.severity ==1),'claims_made']= val
```

Instead you could get an index of the rows you want to assign. Use it to create a series of random integers and when you assign that back to the dataframe, non-indexed rows become NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def claims(dataframe):
    wanted_index = dataframe[df.severity==1].index
    dataframe["claims_made"] = pd.Series(
        np.random.randint(20,20000, size=len(wanted_index)),
        index=wanted_index)
    return dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({"severity":[1, 1, 0, 8, -1, 99, 1]})
print(claims(df))
```

Comment: this is super specific to the point and i wanted exactly this :), cannot thankyou enough, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your existing approach, you could do something like this:

```
def claims2(df):
   n_rows = len(df.loc[(df.severity==1), 'claims_made'])
   vals = [randint(200, 20000) for _ in range(n_rows)]
   df.loc[(df.severity==1), 'claims_made'] = vals
   return df
```

p.s. I'd recommend accessing columns via `df['severity']` instead of `df.severity` -- you can get into trouble using the `.` syntax if you have a dataset with spaces etc. in the column names.

Comment: thankyou for your immediate response, i'm having this checked right away

Comment: @MohammedNadeem - Have you posted a sample dataframe so that we can verify this answer?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure if i can post it because it has confidential data associated with it, but if this idea works, i'll try creating a dummy data frame with some dummy values, i'm still trying the above idea and i am dealing with some errors :) i am a newbee in python , please bear with me

Comment: It doesn't have to be your real data. Just make something up. `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"severity":[1, 0, 0, 1, 9, -4]})`.

Comment: @lefft  this works perfectly fine, sorry for making a mistake in not passing the data frame to the function, thank you so very much

Comment: @tdelaney i have attached the screenshot of the dataframe having the values added for claims, you will be able to see( It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members)

Answer (score -2):

I'll give you a broad hint; coding is up to you.

Form a series (a temporary column object) of random numbers in the desired range.  Assign *that* series to your data frame column.  You can find examples of this technique in any tutorial on data frames.